# Continue after catching exception in AsyncThrowingStream for-try-await (Swift)

Tags: swift, async-await

I'm implementing a *find* method with an AsyncSequence, which is declared like

```
find(text: String) -> AsyncThrowingStream<[Widgets], Error>
```

The method implementation queries multiple sources and the UI is updated incrementally with the results. If one of the sources **throws** an Error, I want to handle it and update the UI with the remaining results.

I was doing this with a *for-try-await* but I'm not sure how the handle the exception. With the code below the iteration stops after an exception is caught (which I'd except by looking at the code, just not sure how to handle the exception with the *for-try-await* syntax such as the iteration continues).

```
var results = [Widgets]()
do {
    for try await items in asyncStream {
        results.append(contentsOf: items)
    }
} catch let error {
    // handle error
}
```

How can I handle the exception without canceling the iteration? E.g. with 3 items in the asyncStream yielding `throws Error, A, B`, the `result` would be [A, B]

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

After taking another look at AsyncThrowingStream documentation

> In contrast to AsyncStream, this type can throw an error from the awaited next(), which terminates the stream with the thrown error.

throwing an error terminates the stream, so the above can't be done with this api. You can, of course, implement your own async sequence. But, given the AsyncSequence semantics it might be confusing to thrown an error and continue. If the error should not terminate the stream maybe it's best to wrap it in the return type.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you may define your `find` method to return data wrapped in the Swift standard `Result` type, like this:

```
func find(text: String) -> AsyncThrowingStream<Result<[Widgets], Error>, Error> {
  AsyncThrowingStream { continuation in
    Task {
      do {
        let result = try await fetchYourWidget(text)
        continuation.yield(.success(result))
      } catch {
        continuation.yield(.failure(error))

        // Perhaps you may log the error here somehow
        print(error)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But, like you eventually said, it may be more idiomatic to implement your own custom `AsyncSequence` type to express this requirement.